# myWidow.close not working with keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to scripting so this is something very basic I was trying to get working. All I am looking to do is to close a window that I have used a greasemonkey script to open with a keypress. Here is what I have so far, I am getting a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined error message and not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
var w = screen.availWidth/2;
var h = screen.availHeight;
var myWindow=window.open(link2,'2' ,'width='+w+', height='+h+', scrollbars=yes,   toolbar=yes');

 document.addEventListener( "keydown", kas, false);
    function kas(i) {
        if (i.keyCode == 65) { //A 

        myWindow.close(); 
        }    
    }
```

Comment: What browser are you running this in? Just tested in chrome and seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks, I actual figured it out, and It was so dumb I hate to admit it. I had to click back in the original window I opened the link from then hit the key and it closed . Like I said I am really new to this . Thanks for the reply .

Comment: I see. Did you want it working when you pressed 'A' in the new window then?

Comment: Yes that was what i was trying to do, basically I'm copy/pasting so with the full script what I am trying to do is when the main page loads , it opens the link, then what I wanted to do is with a keypress to copy then close that window. then another key to fill the original window. I have it working pretty good so for the time being I'll just use a auto hot key script overtop of the java to get it exact.